# Storm Example running even whithout zookeeper, nimbus and supervisor processes

Tags: java, maven, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I have set up a storm node on 1 machine by following the instructions given 
[here](http://10jumps.com/blog/storm-installation-single-machine)

I started the zookeeper, nimbus and supervisor processes as per the instructions.
Then I found storm examples [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) and [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078672/open-source-tools/open-source-java-projects-storm.html), compiled them (using maven) and ran the jar files. They all ran fine.

Then I stopped the supervisor, nimbus and zookeeper processes (in that order) and compiled and ran the example again.

To my surprise, they still compiled and ran as if nothing had changed.
To be absolutely sure that the processes were killed, I shut down my computer and restarted it. This time, I compiled and ran the examples without even starting the zookeeper, nimbus or supervisor processes. They still ran correctly.

Why is this happening and what am I missing?

forgive me if I have missed anything obvious. I am new to Storm and distributed systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out my mistake. I was using LocalCluster to submit the topology, instead of StormSubmitter

Answer (score 1):

Zookeepers role in Storm is to provide service discovery and coordination in a multi-Node Storm Cluster .For single node Storm node it does not have any role.